# Is there a way to get the current Stroke on an InkCanvas?

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas

In UWP I am using an `InkCanvas` to detect strokes. I would like to change the color of the current `Stroke`.
I tried a couple of events but I'm only able to change the color of the `Stroke` after it has been collected through the following event:

```
InkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokesCollected += InkPresenter_StrokesCollected

private void InkPresenter_StrokesCollected(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (InkStroke stroke in InkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes())
    {
        InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
        drawingAttributes.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue;
        stroke.DrawingAttributes = drawingAttributes;
    }
}
```

I also tried the events on `StrokeInput` but I'm unable to find the current Stroke this way.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you want to do with the _current stroke_? Can't you change the `DefaultDrawingAttributes` _before_ the stroke is been drawn?

Comment: @kennyzx I would like to change the color of the stroke is drawn. For example: when the stroke is from left to right a blue color and from right to left an orange color.

Comment: Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-rendering-ink#ImplementingCustomStrokes). Looks promising but I haven't tried this technique yet.

Comment: A heads up: Just found out it is WPF, not UWP. Might not be helpful.